# Unable to update fields on community user record

Tags: community, permissions, user

I am trying to update a field on User record for community user but I am getting insufficient privilege error.
I am able to update the same field on all the users except this one profile I don't have any trigger or validation rule enabled on user record.

Comment: Which field? - there may be a reason that it is not updatable for community users

Comment: Have you check the profile and field level security for the user profile. Can you please add the images for the same.